# Custom Error Page Display Asp.net

Tags: custom-error-pages

If something breaks in my code i was trying to show an custom error page so i have tried the following

1)placing the below in web.config file

```
 <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect= "Error.aspx">
        </customErrors>
      </system.web>
```

2)And tried placing the following in Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
    }
```

3) i tried it having in page level like below

```
 ErrorPage="~/Error.aspx"
```

None of them have worked , The main intention for me to show custom error page is when a value is retrieved from the database it should bind to the screen for the old records we don't have few elements so i thought of showing custom error message ,Please help me /suggest me ( i am using .net framework 4.5)